# How to hide Taskbar in Fullscreen Mode JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently writing a Game with JavaFx. I now want to make the game run in fullscreen mode. I have written the following code:

```
public class Game extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage gameStage) {
        gameStage.setResizable(false);
        gameStage.setMaximized(Settings.fullscreen);
        gameStage.setFullScreen(Settings.fullscreen);
        Settings.changeRoot(StartMenu.getInstance()); //this line just sets my root element
        Scene scene = new Scene(Settings.root,Settings.width,Settings.height);
        gameStage.setScene(scene);
        SoundLoader.getInstance(); //loads sound
        ImageLoader.getInstance(); //loads all ingame images
        gameStage.show();
    }
}
```

The proplem was that it allways showed a popup that said press esc to leave fullscreen mode. I added the following line to remove that text:
    `gameStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);`

The problem now was, that it no longer goes completly into fullscreen mode it allways showes the Toolbar [screenshot that shows how the game is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMfF6.png).
How can I hide the taskbar completly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the game application wasnt in the front that was the reason why the toolbar was infront of it. i added the following line to fix it:

```
gameStage.toFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the text/popup of `Press ESC to leave FullScreen` this way :

```
gameStage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
```

***PS*** : Remove the line you added (`gameStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);` 
 Because I guess this way you won't have to hide any Taskbar.

Comment: thanks for your help the line `gameStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);`
is necessery because without it the game will still leave fullscreen when pressing esc

Comment: So you want to remove the ESC function not only the text ?